# Can I get return via URL

Tags: php, url, return

Can I get return via URL in php like below?

```
$var = http://www.example.com/give_data.php?id=4;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, but i think you want the contents of the file in your variable?
For that you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$var = file_get_contents('http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php');
```

Comment: I don't know why but using this made the php file stuck in a loop and didnt return anything... It just kept loading forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file_get_contents()` as such:

```
$var = file_get_contents('http://www.xyz.com/give_data.php?id=4');
```

But that will just return whatever the give_data.php script outputs as a string. If you need more advanced data-types, I would recommend using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in give_data.php and `$var = json_decode($var);` after getting the data to get back your original data. Note that this won't work for complex PHP objects. If you really really need, you can use serialize() and unserialize(), but it's not as standard and will work in PHP-only.

Comment: If this fails, you may have allow_url_fopen turned off in the ini, or have some safe_mode settings stopping you. In this case look at using cURL to get round it if you cannot get those settings changed, just sayin'.

Comment: Good points, though if you have those restrictions you might want to look for another hoster instead :)

Comment: Using file_get_contents() on an external source just fills me with dread.

Comment: Well, I don't quite see why. The PHP streams are a very powerful feature, and available in core, while curl is not always present. file_get_contents is just a shortcut for fopen/stream_get_contents/fclose. The fact it's called file (which sounds like local filesystem) is just legacy imo.

Comment: You are right, I never thought about it deeply enough 'till now. Having to invoke cURL brings home to me potential dangers of including external data in a higher relief, that is probably a big reason (that and I tend to use multiple streams simultaneously.